# Delay execution of command until after something else has run

Tags: saltstack

I am trying to write a deploy script with salt. It mostly works. I have to run highstate a couple of times for it work all the way. My biggest issue is working through how to execute commands one after another based on specific first one, and them actually finishing/working.

Here is my demo.sls salt state:

```
{% set web_root = "/var/www/demo/" %}

/var/www/venv/demo:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - system_site_packages: False
    - require:
      - pkg: python-virtualenv

demo:
  git.latest:
    - name: git://localhost/demo.git
    - target: {{ web_root }}

demo_pip:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: 'source /var/www/venv/demo/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt'
    - cwd: {{ web_root }}
    - watch:
      - git: demo

run_migrations:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: 'source /var/www/venv/demo/bin/activate && python manage.py syncdb --noinput'
    - cwd: {{ web_root }}
    - watch:
      - cmd: demo_pip

restart_gunicorn:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: supervisorctl restart gunicorn
    - watch:
      - cmd: run_migrations
```

I have set it so that `demo_pip` runs after the git call (which works great), but to be honest `demo_pip` doesn't actually run. The output from salt is that it ran, but none of the requirements in requirements.txt were installed.

I have tried to put the requirements in the `virtualenv.managed` section so that runs it, but I have to run 2 highstates at that point. 1) to get the latest from git, seems to run bot exclusivly 2) to install the requirements. For some reason even after putting the `virtualenv.managed` section after `demo` it still doesn't register the new requirements file.

Am I using the wrong `cmd`? Or do I have an order problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It looks like it was a file/folder permissions problem. I set a `file.managed` for all folders in `/var/www` to be in group `www-data`. Also made sure everything executed as `www-data`, and after that things started working like expected.